# can't make moment-timezone.js work

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I'm trying to use moment.js and moment-timezone.js to make the users able to change into their local timezone. But I'm having some difficulties while using moment-timezone.js . I followed their example, but it doesn't matter which timezone I select it always gives me my local time. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <script src='scripts/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="scripts/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/moment-timezone.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="time">

    </span> 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var dhaka = moment.tz("2015-09-01 12:00", "Asia/Dhaka");

            var newYork = dhaka.clone().tz("America/New_York");
            var losAngeles = dhaka.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
            var london = dhaka.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");



            $('#time').html('Dhaka: ' + dhaka.format() + "<BR>New York: " + newYork.format() + "<br>Los Angeles: " + losAngeles.format() + "<br>London: " + london.format());
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

And my output is:

```
Dhaka: 2015-09-01T12:00:00+00:00
New York: 2015-09-01T12:00:00+00:00
Los Angeles: 2015-09-01T12:00:00+00:00
London: 2015-09-01T12:00:00+00:00
```

Am I doing something wrong? Why it's not working?

Comment: I would like to recommned this to read this one http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Comment: I forgot to add timezone data file. I added that but still same output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js'></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.4.0/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <span id="time">

    </span> 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var dhaka = moment.tz("2015-09-01 12:00", "Asia/Dhaka");

            var newYork = dhaka.clone().tz("America/New_York");
            var losAngeles = dhaka.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
            var london = dhaka.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");

            $('#time').html('Dhaka: ' + dhaka.format() + "<BR>New York: " + newYork.format() + "<br>Los Angeles: " + losAngeles.format() + "<br>London: " + london.format());
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is jsfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/fgvr1rgL/

Comment: Deepak is the boss! :D